# Is there an equivalent of the page-break-after attribute

Tags: html, css

I know that page-break-after is used in printing html documents, but is there a browser equivalent?
Like I have this html:

```
<div class="c1">
 <div>item1</div>
 <div>value11</div>
 <div>value12</div>
 <div>item2</div>
 <div>value21</div>
 <div>value22</div>
</div>
```

and I want to see something like

```
item1   value11   value12
item2   value21   value22
```

The css:

```
.c1 > div{
display:inline-block
}
.c1 > div:nth-child(3n){
????page-break-after
}
```

I need a page break after every third div (:nth-child(3n)), but I can't figure out how to add it. Is there a way to achieve it (without adding new elements)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asuming you cannot alter the DOM (which I would advise), you can fix it with floats and clears:

```
.c1 > div { float: left; margin-right: 10px; }
.c1 > div:nth-of-type(3n+1) { clear: left; }
```

So you're floating the divs, but deny the 4th one to have a element at it's left, and thus forcing it on another line.

**[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/713wgsg1/)**

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to use floats too, but I thought there was a page-break style.